# Get recent based on field for list of users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following model and want to do a filter query on this.

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    user      = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_invite')
    template  = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    user_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I have to filter list of invites for a given list of users for whom the given template is the recent template.

For example:

```
| id | user_id | template | user_time | user_date   |
| -- | --------| -------- | --------- | ----------- |
| 5  | 3       |  temp-A  | 03:40PM   |  19/04/2015 |
| 4  | 1       |  temp-B  | 03:40PM   |  19/04/2015 |
| 3  | 2       |  temp-A  | 03:40PM   |  19/04/2015 |
| 2  | 2       |  temp-B  | 01:30PM   |  17/04/2015 |
| 1  | 1       |  temp-A  | 01:30PM   |  17/04/2015 |
```

Here for user_id 1, the recent template is `temp-B` based on `user_date` and `user_time` and for user_id 2 and 3, it is `temp-A`. Here if the given list of users is `[1,2,3]` and given template is `temp-A`, the result list of IDs should be `[2,3]`.

If I do the query

```
Invite.objects.filter(user_id__in = user_id_list, template = 'temp-A').values_list('user_id', flat = True)
```

the result will be `[1,2,3]` as all the users have received the template `temp-A`. But I want to filter users for whom the given template is the recent one. How to achieve this with django filter queries without using any loops?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the [`greatest-n-per-group`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+django) problem. In Django it can't be solved with a single query, but with two. The following which I'm gonna post is not exactly what you want but very close to it - returns the latest invites per user per max invite id *(not per date as you wanted)*. If you cant use it I hope it will at least give you some directions for the future ones. I will also try to came up with a better solution.

```
invites = Invite.objects.filter(
    id__in=User.objects.filter(
            id__in=[1,2,3],
            user_invite__template='temp-A'
        ).annotate(
            max_invite_id=Max('user_invite__id')
        ).values_list('max_invite_id', flat=True)
)
```